# Pannellum 360 image viewer -Getting pitch and yaw

Tags: javascript, pannellum

Iam trying to work with pannellum.In that how can i get hotspot pitch and yaw in another function.

```html
"pitch":8,
"yaw": 20,
"cssClass": "custom-hotspot2",
"clickHandlerFunc": clickHandlerBox2,
```

I want get that pitch and yaw (8 and 20) in below function
Itried beloow function

```js
function clickHandlerBox2(hotSpotDiv, args) {
var pitch=viewer.getPitch();
var yaw=viewer.getYaw();
}
```

But this one is giving dynamic data according to the pannellum viewer movement.How can I get exactly th same pitch and yaw mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

To get pitch and yaw (8 and 20) try this

```html
"clickHandlerArgs": {"pitch": 8, "yaw": 20},
```

then call it in clickHandlerBox2 function like

```html
args.pitch and args.yaw
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.